# The info.php in localhost wordpress dev is not opening

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, php-ini

I added the code
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>` 
and saved it as **info.php** in my wp-admin. However once I opened it on the browser, it says something like "Oops! That page can’t be found. ".How do I fix this, but if I were to put index.php on the url its working just find just like any other contents in my wp-admin (php) files

http://localhost/WordPress/wp-admin/info.php

P.S Im using MAMP for this dev environment (not MAMP pro).

Comment: why are you adding a file in wp-admin? what do you want to do??